# Generating combinations in order of their sum

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools, combinatorics

Itertools combinations seem to come out in lexicographic order:

```
>>> for c in combinations([9,8,7,2,2,1], 2):
...     print(c, sum(c))
... 
(9, 8) 17
(9, 7) 16
(9, 2) 11
(9, 2) 11
(9, 1) 10
(8, 7) 15
(8, 2) 10
(8, 2) 10
(8, 1) 9
(7, 2) 9
(7, 2) 9
(7, 1) 8
(2, 2) 4
(2, 1) 3
(2, 1) 3
```

But I want to generate them in order of greatest sum:

```
>>> for c in sorted(combinations([9,8,7,2,2,1], 2), key=sum, reverse=True):
...     print(c, sum(c))
... 
(9, 8) 17
(9, 7) 16
(8, 7) 15
(9, 2) 11
(9, 2) 11
(9, 1) 10
(8, 2) 10
(8, 2) 10
(8, 1) 9
(7, 2) 9
(7, 2) 9
(7, 1) 8
(2, 2) 4
(2, 1) 3
(2, 1) 3
```

Actually generating them all and sorting is not possible because the result is too large (this is a smaller example).

I thought it might be possible to modify the recipe offered in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) as "roughly equivalent" python code:

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

But could not figure it out.

If it helps, `r` will always be 2 and the input (~10k elements) is small enough that it could be sorted to a monotonically non-increasing list.

There's also a rejection criteria that is expensive to compute. So it's not just the first combo which is selected, but the largest combo (by sum) that was not rejected after checking another condition. The vast majority of combos are rejected - we'll have to go through about 0.1% of them before finding one that is not rejected.

Comment: `...the result is too large...` - How large? Can you push the `(sum,(combo))` on a heap as they are generated?

Comment: @wwii it is around 10k for the input list, which means around 50M for the combos

Comment: @JosephWood I've tried it, but that was quite slower than the naive approach I was already using (nested for-loops, checking the largest element against all others, then the second-largest against all others less-than-equal, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort in reverse. Then each number can be paired  with all later numbers, providing a sequence of pairs with non-ascending sums. Merge all these sequences.

```
from heapq import merge

def combinations(xs):
    xs.sort(reverse=True)
    def pairs(ix):
        i, x = ix
        for j in range(i+1, len(xs)):
            yield x, xs[j]
    return merge(
        *map(pairs, enumerate(xs)),
        key=sum,
        reverse=True
    )

for c in combinations([9,8,7,2,2,1]):
    print(c, sum(c))
```

Alternative version, having fun with iteration tools:

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import repeat
from copy import copy

def combinations(xs):
    xs.sort(reverse=True)
    it = iter(xs)
    return merge(
        *map(zip,
             map(repeat, it),
             map(copy, repeat(it))),
        key=sum,
        reverse=True
    )

for c in combinations([9,8,7,2,2,1]):
    print(c, sum(c))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, and much faster than the code in the proposed duplicate. I am curious what is the time/space complexity of this approach?

Comment: @nosteponsnek O(n) space for the iterators and heap. O(n + klogn) time for setup and iterating the first k pairs.

Comment: @nosteponsnek I see you unaccepted. Is there an issue?

Comment: @nosteponsnek Yes, you can't delete questions with upvoted answers. That would also delete the answers, which would delete something useful and be rather rude. Also, more people might find the answer or the question useful in the future. I had actually upvoted your question after you added the extra infos, then just took it back because I realized  you had unaccepted the answer, as that indicated that there's something wrong with it and that I don't understand the question and thus can't judge it yet. Now that you said there's no issue, I'll upvote again, and hope you'll reconsider as well.